# C++ Win32 Window Overlap Event

Tags: c++, winapi, window, paint, overlap

I am creating a window and drawing some lines on it. I have done the option to choose the line color using CHOOSECOLOR. The problem is when the color dialog is shown, as it moves (dragged) across the window the drawn lines are erased (like the eraser in MS Paint).

I have managed to redraw what was erased after the color dialog closes successfully. But It's really better to redraw instantly as the color dialog moves.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you drawing the lines in your `WM_PAINT` handler?

Comment: Is your `WM_PAINT` handler getting called?

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't understand "calling WM_PAINT". Sorry.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your `WM_PAINT` handler. This might be the `case WM_PAINT` in your window procedure or an `OnPaint` method or something else provided by your framework. Verify that the breakpoint is hit. Verify that when you step through your paint handler, you draw the lines.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` is a message that is automatically generated by Windows when some or all of your window needs redrawing, for whatever reason. One such reason is when part of your window is uncovered by another window.

Answer (score 0):

Save your figures in linked list or array, and every time redraw everything that you have in data structure.

Comment: I have done that. But they get redrawn only after the color dialog is closed, not as it moves.

As you said in your answerm "every time". I want to detect that "every time", the event where my window is overlapped by another window, if such event exists.